# Android Activity Setting

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

**How to put this " + " signn on bottom right corner in my activity and set some funtion for this activity**

Comment: Thats floating action button(FAB) search for it

Comment: I'm pretty sure the "New Activity" templates already have this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood your question, you are saying about `fab` button or floating action button, a new material design element.It is available by adding [Design Support Library](https://developer.android.com/training/material/design-library.html).

```
<!-- find a plus icon -->
 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:src="@drawable/ic_plus"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: You checked the link? Put the view inside the activity root layout, to understand structure you can use new activity option from latest android studio and select a proper template with fab button in it !